# Having trouble with recursive SQL over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, recursion

I'm rewriting one of our inhouse financial systems. What I'm setting up is that this new system takes a snapshot of the order table every month and date that snapshot. This part works great.

Next step is that I create a view that will contain the totals for every month, and the totals for it's previous month.

When I do a total by team and month, I have no problem setting up the recursion. I just do a natural join on team, and month=month-1 (I setup a separate table for the month with an identity to make life easier)

Where I'm running into problems is that if I try to do the recursion at the same time as I do the join. I'm joining on team and month again, but I'm ending up with a cross join for some reason. Is there an easy reason to see what's causing the cross join? And does anyone see an error in my logic?
Here's the join:

```
select SH1.month, SH1.Team,
   sum(SH2.Monthly_SAMT) as BilledPrevious, sum(SH1.Monthly_SAMT) as BilledCurrent,
   sum(SH1.Monthly_SAMT) - sum(SH2.MonthlyAnnualized_SAMT) BILLEDDIFF
from vw_SalesMonthly2 SH1 full outer join vw_SalesMonthly2 SH2
   on SH1.team=SH2.team and SH1.month_index-1 = SH2.month_index
group by SH1.month, SH1.Team
order by 1 desc, 2 asc
```

Comment: I think you should try a recursive CTE. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `OUTER APPLY` here to get the previous sums.

```
SELECT  SH1.month,
        SH1.Team,
        COALESCE(SH2.Monthly_SAMT,0) AS BilledPrevious,
        SUM(SH1.Monthly_SAMT) AS BilledCurrent,
        SUM(SH1.Monthly_SAMT) - COALESCE(SH2.MonthlyAnnualized_SAMT,0) BILLEDDIFF
FROM    vw_SalesMonthly2 SH1
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(SH2.Monthly_SAMT) Monthly_SAMT,
                            SUM(SH2.MonthlyAnnualized_SAMT) MonthlyAnnualized_SAMT
                     FROM   vw_SalesMonthly2 SH2
                     WHERE  SH1.team = SH2.team
                            AND SH1.month_index - 1 = SH2.month_index
                    ) SH2
GROUP BY SH1.month,
        SH1.Team,
        SH2.Monthly_SAMT,
        SH2.MonthlyAnnualized_SAMT
ORDER BY 1 DESC,
        2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the data all summarized by month before you do the join to get the previous months data. Therefore, you need to group before you join.

Also, I think you want a left join rather than full outer. You want one row per month/team, with previous month's data for each row if it exists, right?

Here's a toy example:

```
declare @sales table (id int identity, team integer, mon integer, value money)
insert @sales (team, mon, value) values 
    (1,1,0),
    (1,2,100),
    (1,3,150),
    (2,1,40),
    (2,2,99)

; with cte as (
    select team, mon, sum(value) [value]
    from @sales
    group by team, mon
)
select s1.team, s1.mon, s1.value, s2.value [previous]
from cte s1
left join cte s2 on s1.team=s2.team and s1.mon=s2.mon+1
order by 1 asc, 2 asc
```

Output:

```
team        mon         value                 previous
----------- ----------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           1           0.00                  NULL
1           2           100.00                0.00
1           3           150.00                100.00
2           1           40.00                 NULL
2           2           99.00                 40.00
```